# How to get swift package version at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Hi I am needing to get a swift package version at runtime. How would this be executed? Best if possible to complete through the command line.

Comment: Runtime, command line, iOS tag, this is confusing and contradictory

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you say "through the command line" you mean "using Swift code", you will need to expose the version in some way, like a global constant. Then you can have script that changes the value this constant and also the package version (i.e. git tag).

Note that if you distribute a framework, and store its version in its Info.plist, then Xcode will change that version when your clients upload their app to the app store. (You can use [this workaround](https://ootips.org/yonat/getting-your-framework-version-in-run-time/) if that what you're after.)

Comment: It is a third party swift-package that I am needing the version number of. I was hoping to get it from the package.swift file but it is not listed.

Comment: That would depend on the specific package you use. Do you want to write its name here?